# Create different template class according to the basic type of the template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, type-constraints, template-inheritance

I will try to explain my problem with a simple example:

```
class Runnable
{
protected:
    virtual bool Run() { return true; };
};

class MyRunnable : Runnable
{
protected:
    bool Run()
    {
        //...
        return true;
    }
};

class NotRunnable
{ };

class FakeRunnable
{
protected:
    bool Run()
    {
        //...
        return true;
    }
};
```

```
//RUNNABLE must derive from Runnable
template<class RUNNABLE>
class Task : public RUNNABLE
{
public:
    template<class ...Args>
    Task(Args... args) : RUNNABLE(forward<Args>(args)...)
    { }

    void Start()
    {
        if(Run()) { //... }
    }
};
```

```
typedef function<bool()> Run;

template<>
class Task<Run>
{
public:
    Task(Run run) : run(run)
    { }

    void Start()
    {
        if(run()) { //... }
    }

private:
    Run run;
};
```

main.cpp

```
Task<MyRunnable>();                //OK: compile
Task<Run>([]() { return true; });  //OK: compile
Task<NotRunnable>();               //OK: not compile
Task<FakeRunnable>();              //Wrong: because compile
Task<Runnable>();                  //Wrong: because compile
```

In summary, if the `T` template derive from the `Runnable` class,  I want the `class Task : public RUNNABLE` class to be used. If the template `T` is of the `Run` type I want the `class Task<Run>` class to be used, and in all other cases the program does not have to compile.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might `static_assert` your condition (with traits [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)):

```
template<class RUNNABLE>
class Task : public RUNNABLE
{
public:
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Runnable, RUNNABLE>::value
                  && !std::is_same<Runnable , RUNNABLE>::value);

    // ...
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/108292fa5da0d211)

Comment: Okay, great solution, I modified my initial question slightly making the ```Runnable``` class not abstract.

Comment: `std::is_base_of<Runnable , Runnable >::value` is true. if it is your concern.

Comment: But I want it to return false

Comment: You can still add and `&& !std::is_same<Runnable , RUNNABLE>::value`.